# Question about 3 types of model in Anylogic

Tags: model, anylogic

I know there are three main types of models in Anylogic: ABM, DES and SD. I would like to know what these three types of models have in common (or Similarities)? And what are their main differences? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, SOF is not suitable for this type of general questions. You can use LinkedIn for this type of questions.

Comment: As Yashar said please post these type of questions here - https://www.linkedin.com/groups/1524407/

Comment: And follow this guide to learn more about the AnyLogic community and what to ask where (welcome :) ): https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community

Comment: Also, please always check the help first, there is a ton of material on this: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/ui/approaches-index.html

Comment: The [tag:des] tag is for questions about the Data Encryption Standard (DES) is a cryptographic block cipher algorithm not Discrete Event Simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is not really a SO question, I will answer this anyways in the most summarized possible way:

ABM is modeling based on agents. An agent can be anything that can be on a discrete form. The main idea is that agents are in states and have the ability to communicate with other agents.

DES is modeling based on processes. The main idea is that you construct a process flow in which agents flow in a sequence of sub-processes.

SD is modeling the dynamics of a system. The main idea is that things accumulate and flow, so you can construct a mathematical model based on differential equations that can represent any system. System dynamics is the graphical representation of these differential equations using stocks (where things accumulate) and flow.

SD has absolutely nothing in common with the other 2, and it's also continuous in nature (you can have 3.4 people without problem). You generally work with averages and not with distributions, which makes it a very high level view of a system without any details on any actor of the system.

DE and AB are discrete in nature (you can only have 3,4,5 people). They both have agents in it but technically in DE you dont have access to the agent as an individual, so you see the process as the main concept that you can play with and measure.

in AB you only see individuals and you don't see the system as a whole, only the consequences in the system based on the individual actions of the agents.